# How to fix Data.map is not a function in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, map-function

So I have a Notesdata array containing object with properties title, tagline, description. Notesdata  array is stored in the "data" state variable in the App component and I am sending this data state variable to notes view component to populate on the UI but when I am appending a new object inside the data state variable and then sending it to notesview component, I am getting the error "Data.map is not a function".

When I am printing the "data" state variable I am getting an array but when I am checking its type it's showing "object", I am confused in why it is showing like that.

I also tried using Array.from() on the "data" state variable before passing it to notesview but that is also showing the same error.

[image: the first console.log is showing object which is the typeof "data" state variable while in second line it is actual "data" state variable in array form]

------------App component------------------

```
   import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import Input from './Components/Input';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Notesview from './Components/Notesview';
import Notesdata from "./Data/Notesdata";

function App() {
  // const [data, setdata] = useState(Notesdata);
  const [data, setData] = useState(Notesdata);

  function handleDelete(id) {

    let newData = data.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
    setData(newData)
  }

  function handlePost(value) {
    let newval = data.push(value)
    setData(newval)
    console.log(typeof data)
    console.log(data)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar />
        <Input data={data} handlePost={(value) => handlePost(value)} />
        <Notesview handleDelete={handleDelete} Data={data} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

-----------------notesview component-----------------------

```
import React from 'react'
import Notescard from './Notescard'
import "../Styles/Notes.css"

const Notesview = ({ Data, handleDelete }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <div className='notes'>
        {
          Data.map((item) => {    // here is the Data.map where the error is coming
            return <Notescard item={item} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Notesview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot wrong right here:

```
let newval = data.push(value)
setData(newval)
console.log(typeof data)
console.log(data)
```

1. `Array.prototype.push` returns the *length* of the array, so you're setting `data` to a *number*.  (Which, incidentally, does not have a `.map()` function.)
2. You're mutating a state value (`data`) before trying to update it.  Just update it.
3. You're trying to examine the value after it's been updated, but you're examining the *current* value and not the *new* value.  State updates are asynchronous.

To update the state correctly, you'd do something more like this:

```
setData([...data, value]);
```

If you might have a batch of updates and you want each state update to use the updating state in the batch rather than the current state in the render, you could use the callback version of the state setter:

```
setData(d => [...d, value]);
```

This creates a new array reference, which includes all of the elements in the `data` array as well as the new `value` element, and sets that reference as the updated state.  Without mutating the current state for the current render.

Comment: thank you it worked but I am like little confused here, I was following a tutorial of a different project in react, he also used same .push method but he was able to successfully populate the data , why it dint work here in my project ?     His code ->                                        
 function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const ids = uuid()
    let uniqueId = ids.slice(0,8)
    let a = name;
    let b = age;
    Employees.push({id: uniqueId ,Name: a, Age:b})
    history("/")
  }

Comment: @ApoorvSharma: That code doesn't indicate at all what `Employees` is or how it's used, only that it's an array.  You can certainly use `.push()` on an array in JavaScript.  However, specific to React, you don't want to directly modify (mutate) state values but instead want to use the state setter functions and let the framework manage updating those values.  `.push()` directly modifies the array.

Comment: ok got it , just one more doubt like what if i push the new object directly to original array that is "Notesdata" and then using setter function to set updated "Notesdata " ?? Something like this --->   function handlePost(value) {
     Notesdata.push(value)
    setData(Notesdata)
  }

Comment: @ApoorvSharma: Depending on the implementation in `Notesdata` that *might* work.  But it presents risks.  If `Notesdata` is just a literal JSON structure then that operation *implies* that the new value is being persisted in some way, which can at a glance confuse you or a future developer.  It's also possible that the state value is using the same array reference, at least temporarily, and you don't want to mutate that array.  It also begs the question of which is the system of record?  The originating data, or the current state?  You'll want to be clear on how your data is managed.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because Data is `null`. you can check `Data`'s existence before trying to map on it in `Notesview` like this:

```
Data && Data.map(...)
```